# Yii Framework - New webapp without ssh access

Tags: yii, ssh

How can I create a new webapp in Yii Framework without ssh access?

I'm following the tutorials, bui I don't have ssh access to the server.

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you read that ssh is required? Use command line.

Comment: I don't have access to the server command line, I use an external server, accessible only by FTP.

Comment: Just download one of the demos like the blog and remove all the Controllers, Models, and Views. You may want to leave the SiteController and site views. Then upload them via ftp.

Comment: Or you could install WAMP or something like it on your computer run the command line tools, to create site locally. Then upload files.

Comment: Thanks Pitchinnate, I will try to install WAMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download one of the demos like the blog and remove all the Controllers, Models, and Views. You may want to leave the SiteController and site views. Then upload them via ftp.

Or you could install WAMP or something like it on your computer run the command line tools, to create site locally. Then upload files.